# Calculate volume of a polygon using leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a polygon and a Digital terrain model, I need to find a way to calculate the 3d volume of the area inside the polygon on leaflet.
Is it possible to achieve it using some sort of formula or do I need an external library?

Comment: Are you actually rendering the DTM in Leaflet, ie, you have a grid of x,y, z values client side? If so, as it is a regular grid, it ought to be pretty straight forward to calculate the volume. I am reasonably certain that no Leaflet plugin/library will exist for what you are asking, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Supposing i have a grid of x,y and z values what should be the formula to calculate the 3d volume based on the polygon ?

Comment: There is no such Leaflet plugin. Have a look at this library: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/13666/polyhedra-volume-calculations-a-javascript-impleme

Comment: It is a DEM, so a regular grid, so no need for a polyhedral calculator. Calculate the area of intersection of each DEM square with the polygon using turfjs or similar, multiply each one by the height of DEM, sum.